# Two way Google Form notifications with conditions

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I am new to Google forms and I am looking for some add-on or script to send form submission notifications to different people. There are add-ons to implement this functionality but I want to send emails with conditions. For example, if option "food" is selected by respondent then this email notification will be sent to a person who is responsible for food department. Similarly I have 3 other options and 3 other email addresses. I am not able to find solution for it. Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The Data Director Add-on has "Advanced Branching".  It will check different conditions for multiple different Form questions.  [Chrome Web Store - Forms Add-ons](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/data-director-for-forms/bjlicikmbfbjckkgemmiddonmigijpbj?authuser=0)  Use the email settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution is to write Google script to send emails. A simple tutorial is: http://www.jeffreyeverhart.com/2014/01/31/tech-tip-how-to-send-a-confirmation-email-with-google-forms/